# is ValuesQuerySet an evaluated form of queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

When you perform certain operations on queryset such as len or slicing, you hit DB and query is evaluated.

Is ValuesQuerySet returned from `values() or values_list()` already evaluated? 
i.e. Did it already hit DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `ValuesQuerySet` is not evaluated:

```
>>> from app.models import *
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> qs = Question.objects.all().values()
>>> len(connection.queries) # no db hit
0
>>> v = list(qs)
>>> len(connection.queries) # db hit
1
```

Comment: Does `len(connection.queries)` return # of DB hits?

Comment: Yes. `connection.queries` contains a list of SQL queries executed in the current connection.